# Find the radius of circle, given tangents from three vertices of a square

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, plane-geometry

[image]

The above is the image of the question. The brown, blue, green lines are tangent to the circle and the measure of a side of the square is 10. The question is to find the value of the radius.

My Attempt:

I took O as the centre of the circle and drew radius to the tangent point of each tangent. Then I found the lengths of the lines joining the circumcenter and each vertex of the square. But I didn't find any useful relations among the attempts I tried.

So anyone in this community could help me with this question.

Sorry for the bad writing in the picture.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Cute problem. What is its source?

Comment: @MyMolecules found it on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9VK5oUvy4c

Comment: Oh its a youtube video. Don't they give solutions?

Comment: @MyMolecules gave but it's not understandable

Comment: I asked just out of curiosity. I have added an answer with an interesting approach. And +1 to the problem.

Comment: In high school geometry (at least in the 1960's) there was a topic: "power of a point with respect to a circle".  Perhaps that material is assumed for this problem.

Comment: @Bometh it's a simple application of Pythagoras: $R^2 + 8^2 - 3^2 = (10-R)^2 \implies R = 9/4$. The key property to remember is that from any given point external to the circle, there are two tangents to the circle, equal in length. So the circle must be tangent to the top side of the square.

Comment: @MathLover Thank you very much!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ekahRnky-wQ After some time found the answer as  a video on YouTube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an interesting setup and we can try to understand the geometry of it.

Let us first drop the diagram on the coordinate plane. The square has vertices $A(0,0), B(10,0),C(10,10),D(0,10)$. The given circle has center $O(h,k)$.

[image]

Take circles at $A,C,D$ of radius $8,7,3$ respectively. The tangent lengths indicate that these three circles cut the given circle at right angles. Hence the center of given circle is meeting point of the common chords/tangents (also known as radical center) of the three new circles.

Notice that $7+3=10$. This means circles $\odot(C),\odot(D)$ are tangent on the side of the square and their common tangent (radical axis) is at $x=3$. So $h=3$.

To compute the $y$-coordinate, we can find the equation of common chord of circles $\odot(A),\odot(D)$. This is found by equating the equations of $\odot(A),\odot(D)$.

$$x^2+y^2-8^2=x^2+(y-10)^2-3^2$$
$$\Rightarrow y=31/4 =k$$

Hence center of purple circle is at $(3,31/4)$. It follows that its radius is $$10-31/4=9/4=\boxed{2.25}$$

---

Alternatively, as @MathLover says, once we realized that the purple circle is tangent to side $CD$ of the square, we can apply Pythagoras to write $AO^2$ in two ways :
$$r^2+8^2=3^2+(10-r)^2$$

Comment: But can the radical center property be stated in a simple way? At least for this case of tangent circles.

Comment: @Joce, yes. Beginning with $OD^2-DT^2=OC^2-CT^2$,  there is elementary solution.

Comment: But how do you show that the tangents passing thru D and C have the same point of tangency T?

Answer (score 2):

HINT...let the coordinates of the centre of the circle be $(x,y)$ with the bottom left-hand corner of the square being the origin.
Then, considering distances from the origin and from other corners of the square to the centre of the circle, you have:
$$x^2+y^2=64+r^2$$
$$x^2+(10-y)^2=9+r^2$$ and
$$(10-x)^2+(10-y)^2=49+r^2$$

You can solve these simultaneously to get $x$ and $y$ and hence get $r$.

Comment: I have been looking for a geometric solution using barycentric coordinates but also had to fall back to introducing cartesian coordinates - and this would have led to a much more complicated solution procedure.